# Parsing an external HTML page with PHP

Tags: php, html-parsing

I am trying to use the country detection by IP, an API from http://www.hostip.info/use.html

So if you put in your browser something like:
http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=12.24.25.26

then the page will write "US"...

Now my question is how can I use this in a IF ELSE lopp in my php code? I think I have to parse that HTML page, but at the moment I have no clue, some help would be appriciated!

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to check? If it is US?

Comment: Yes, something that return true if it is US or false if it is something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since that page does not output anything other than the country code, there is no parsing required. A simple check on the returned HTML will do it.

```
<?php
$ip = '12.24.25.26';
$country = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip='.$my_ip); // Get the actual HTML

if($country === "US") {
    echo "It is US";
} else {
    echo "It is not US. It is " . $country;
}
```

Comment: It's not contects! It's contents! And the output of the `file_get_contents()` function could be trimmed with the `trim()` function.

Answer (score 4):

[CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) should do what you need it to do.

```
$url = "http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=[put_your_ip_here]";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if(preg_match('/^us$/i', $output)) {
  echo 'Is US';
} else {
  echo 'Something else';
}
```

Comment: And why is this a problem? `curl` generally performs faster than `file_get_contents` and allows you to set more verbose settings. There's no reason why it's not a viable alternative to `file_get_contents`.

Comment: Thanks, this adds a 1 at the end of the outpot. eg US1 Also I think it is a bit slower than file_get_contents ??

Comment: @atno curl is alot faster and more flexible then file_get_contents

Comment: @Sean87 That was my bad, forgot to add `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`. Without that, `curl_exec` returns 1 and outputs the page. Updated code works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following.Change `$my_ip` to what ever IP you like.

```
<?php
$my_ip = '12.24.25.26';
$my_country = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip='.$my_ip);

if(strstr($my_country,'US'))
{
    echo $my_country . ' found.';
}
elseif(strstr($my_country,'XX'))
{
    echo 'IP: ' . $my_ip . 'doesn\'t exists in database';
}
```

Comment: Typo in function name, can you fix.

Comment: Thanks, this partially works but it returns to me XX for each IP I test, could be some language argument for that function should be used or something?

Comment: @Sean87 No, the IP just doesn't exist in their database.

Comment: @Sean87 added functionality to check if IP exists in their database.